# Why stars twinkle but planets don't?

Tags: astronomy, visible-light, planets, atmospheric-science, stars

I am not from a physics background. I came to know this while studying probability? Is this because the planets are nearer than the stars so we get average behaviour rather than random. Is law of large number used here? Can anyone explain in detail.

Comment: Thought the text of [Why do stars flicker?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/68200/why-do-stars-flicker?rq=1#) does not mention planets, the answer covers this exactly.

Comment: Guys...we should rather answer a question than marking it as a duplicate.

Comment: @Sid you might wanna take that up on [meta](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/)